# haxe -lib nme -> /usr/local/bin/libneko.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Tags: haxe

I tried install haxe & nme in MacOSX 10.7.4

```
 brew install haxe
 brew install neko
 haxe -lib nme
```

but...

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/libneko.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/haxelib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/bin/libneko.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/username/lib/libneko.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20

lipo -info /usr/local/bin/haxelib
Non-fat file: /usr/local/bin/haxelib is architecture: i386
lipo -info /usr/local/bin/libneko.dylib
Non-fat file: /usr/local/bin/libneko.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

How should a problem be solved? 
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds messy... Could you try uninstalling from brew, and then using the [installer on the Haxe website](http://haxe.org/download) instead? If that doesn't help post a comment and I'll ask someone on the mailing list to help answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if you have a 64 bit machine (your mac), but are running 32 bit neko.
There's [similar bug reports](https://github.com/openfl/lime-tools/issues/51) on haxe related forums.

If you're installing neko via brew, make sure there's not another version of those neko libs lurking on your system somewhere.  That can trip the same error.